# Fix overscan for HDMI output to HDTV in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, display, hdmi, xrandr

I am using an old laptop running Xubuntu 16.04 as a media center.

However, I cannot seem to *properly* fix the overscan that occurs when using my 1080p HDTV as the display. I am NOT using any proprietary display drivers.

I am aware that some TV's have overscan settings of their own. I have already done my research and found that my TV has very limited options for changing the overscan settings (its an inexpensive Seiki TV). So I need to adjust the display settings within Xubuntu. In Windows, I have the same problem and I usually have to scale the display about 70% for it to fit correctly.

I have tried several solutions using **xrandr**, but none have worked. Most solutions I have found online simply destroy the resolution and even the mouse borders.

Does anyone have any suggestions?